# POS Tagging in NLP

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, katacoda

I am doing a course in NLTK Python which has a hands-on problem(on Katacoda) on "Text Corpora" and it is not accepting my solution mentioned below. Have been stuck on this problem since long. Need to complete this hands-on to proceed foreword in course.

## Problem Defenition

1. Import the text corpus brown.
2. Extract the list of tagged words from the corpus brown. Store the result in brown_tagged_words
3. Generate trigrams of brown_tagged_words and store the result in brown_tagged_trigrams.

4.For every trigram of brown_tagged_trigrams, determine the tags associated with each word. This results in a list of tuples, where each tuple contain pos tags of 3 consecutive words, occurring in text. Store the result in brown_trigram_pos_tags.

5.Determine the frequency distribution of brown_trigram_pos_tags and store the result in brown_trigram_pos_tags_freq.
6.Print the number of occurrences of trigram ('JJ','NN','IN')

For this I have tried below solution:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown
brown_tagged_words = [w for w in brown.tagged_words()]
brown_tagged_trigrams = nltk.trigrams(brown_tagged_words)
brown_trigram_pos_tags = [(w1[1],w2[1],w2[1]) for w1,w2,w3 in brown_tagged_trigrams]
brown_trigram_pos_tags_freq = nltk.FreqDist(brown_trigram_pos_tags)
print(brown_trigram_pos_tags_freq[('JJ', 'NN', 'IN')])
```

Comment: But what is your question? Have you read about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: I have modified my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`brown_trigram_pos_tags = [(w1[1],w2[1],w3[1]) for w1,w2,w3 in brown_tagged_trigrams]`

Here change W2 to w3,this will give value around 8

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
('IN', 'AT', 'AT')
```

You will get the result:
43271

you are getting 0 because there is no occurrence of ('JJ', 'NN', 'IN').

Comment: Hello Chandan, I tried already as you referred, But its not accepting as Solution..Got message as Please Continue your task before Proceeding. I couldn't understand the statement, "occurring in text".

Comment: I mean to saw that there is no combination of ('JJ', 'NN', 'IN') in brown corpus text which you are looking for.

Comment: Got your Point, But Couldn't able finish this task Yet.

Comment: @MuralitharanSathyamoorthy please explain your problem statement in detail.

Comment: Which scenerio are you working on katacoda, I am not able to understand here.

Comment: brown_trigram_pos_tags = [(w1[1],w2[1],w2[1]) for w1,w2,w3 in brown_tagged_trigrams] , it's typo Error instead w3, gave w2 in this line. Thanks. Finally found it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown
brown_tagged_words = brown.tagged_words()
brown_tagged_trigrams = [(w1,w2,w3) for w1,w2,w3 in nltk.trigrams(brown_tagged_words)]
brown_trigram_pos_tags = [(w1[1],w2[1],w2[1]) for w1,w2,w3 in 
brown_tagged_trigrams]
brown_trigram_pos_tags_freq = nltk.FreqDist(brown_trigram_pos_tags)
print(brown_trigram_pos_tags_freq[('JJ', 'NN', 'IN')])
```

Try this...

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, while this may answer the question, it is better to give explanations and not only code for your answer.